# Facebook is working only on first time app start after install, not if restart the app

Tags: ios, swift3, facebook-ios-sdk

I have integrated FB SDK in my app. If i install my app and try to login for the first time then it is working fine. But if i do not login and restart my app, then it is not working and stoping in the webView as show in below screen shot. Not able to figure out why second time it does not work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
first import below in your viewcontroller:

    #import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
    #import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
    #import <FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h>
    #import <FBSDKLoginManager.h>


- (IBAction)LoginWithFacebookButton_Clicked:(id)sender
{
    NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookies = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    NSArray* facebookCookies = [cookies cookiesForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://login.facebook.com"]];
    for (NSHTTPCookie* cookie in facebookCookies)
    {
        [cookies deleteCookie:cookie];
    }

    [FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil];
    [FBSDKProfile setCurrentProfile:nil];

    FBSDKLoginManager *manager=[[FBSDKLoginManager alloc]init];
    [manager logOut];

    if ([AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager].networkReachabilityStatus==AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable)
    {
        [STMethod showInternetToast:self.view];
        return;
    }

    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];

    login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;

    [login logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile",@"email"]fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult result,NSError error)
    {
        if (error)
         {
             NSLog(@"Process error");
         }
         else if (result.isCancelled)
         {
             NSLog(@"Cancelled");
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"Logged in");

             FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                           initWithGraphPath:@"/me"
                                           parameters:@{@"fields": @"id,name,email,first_name,last_name,gender,birthday,picture.type(large)",}
                                           HTTPMethod:@"GET"];

             [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection connection, id Userresult, NSError error)
              {
                  //Insert your code here
              }    


#pragma  mark - Checking for facebook user

 AFHTTPSessionManager*manager=[[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]init];

   manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];

                  NSDictionary *parameters=@{@"fb_id":[Userresult valueForKey:@"id"],@"device_token":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[USERDEFAULT valueForKey:kToken]],@"device_type":@"ios"};

                  [manager POST:WS_FacebookLogin parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * Nonnull task, id  Nonnull responseObject)
                   {


                   }
                        failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask  _Nonnull task, NSError  _Nonnull error)
                   {

                   }];

              }];
         }
     }];
}
```